# How to find a key in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a  multidimensional array and i need make a searchCategory($categories, $id) function, which have to return a value of 'title' properties.

it try this code, it work but only for one layer of multidimensional array.

Multidimensional array:

```
$categories = array(    array(
    "id" => 1,
    "title" =>  "Обувь",
    'children' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Ботинки',
            'children' => array(
                array('id' => 3, 'title' => 'Кожа'),
                array('id' => 4, 'title' => 'Текстиль'),
            ),
        ),
        array('id' => 5, 'title' => 'Кроссовки',),
    )),     array(
    "id" => 6,
    "title" =>  "Спорт",
    'children' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 7,
            'title' => 'Мячи'
        )
    )   ), );
```

Code which i try solve problem:

```
function searchCategory($categories, $id) {

    foreach($categories as $category) {

        if($category['id'] == $id) {

            echo $category['title'] . '<br>';

        }
    } 
};
```

I need my function to look up the id value in all arrays and return the title in the case of the array found

Comment: You are missing another foreach loop to iterate over the elements in the inner arrays. Try doing this: ```foreach ($category as $key=>$value)
{   echo "$key: $value }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make your function recursively

Demo : https://3v4l.org/CR7CD

```
function searchCategory($categories, $id) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        if($category['id'] == $id)
            echo $category['title'] . '<br>';
        if(isset($category['children']))
            searchCategory($category['children'],$id);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is recursive iterator case for you, please go through inline doc for explanation

```
function searchCategory($categories, $id)
{
    $arrayiter = new RecursiveArrayIterator($categories);
    $iteriter  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($arrayiter);
    foreach ($iteriter as $key => $value) {
        // checking if iterator comes to point where key is id and value matched
        if ($key == 'id' && $value == $id) {
            // returning matched value with current iterator instance
            return $iteriter->getInnerIterator()['title'];
        }
    }
    return '';
}
echo searchCategory($categories, 2).'<br/>';
echo searchCategory($categories, 7);
```

[Working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b4a4df113116fb89beb4824c4c0f8d6692f9ca6).

[RecursiveArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) - This iterator allows to unset and modify values and keys while iterating over Arrays and Objects in the same way as the [ArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php). Additionally it is possible to iterate over the current iterator entry.
[RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) - Can be used to iterate through recursive iterators.
[RecursiveIteratorIterator::getInnerIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getinneriterator.php): Get inner iterator